# Backstage failed to start up: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/plugins/xxx]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, backstage

I have a plugin named "inventory-backend". It includes Knex migrations folder, "migrations". It works fine locally.

Here, I created a Docker image, completely following Backstage Docs (https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/k8s/ and https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/docker/). Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 g++ build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

USER node

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --chown=node:node yarn.lock package.json packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz ./
RUN tar xzf skeleton.tar.gz && rm skeleton.tar.gz

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 300000

COPY --chown=node:node packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz app-config*.yaml ./
RUN tar xzf bundle.tar.gz && rm bundle.tar.gz

CMD ["node", "packages/backend", "--config", "app-config.yaml"]
```

Next, I'm deploying Postgre and Backstage, again, in the way that docs suggest. But the pod that gets created with the deployment gets this error:

`Backend failed to start up [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/plugins/inventory-backend/migrations'] { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'scandir', path: '/app/plugins/inventory-backend/migrations' }`

When I look inside the container, I don't see my "migrations" folder. So I added this line to Dockerfile:

`COPY plugins/inventory-backend/migrations /app/plugins/inventory-backend/migrations`

Now when I check inside the container, I see that migrations folder is there. But it gives me the same error. How can this happen?

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16 || 18"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn start\" \"yarn start-backend\"",
    "start": "yarn workspace app start",
    "start-backend": "yarn workspace backend start",
    "build:backend": "yarn workspace backend build",
    "build:all": "backstage-cli repo build --all",
    "build-image": "yarn workspace backend build-image",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:full": "tsc --skipLibCheck false --incremental false",
    "clean": "backstage-cli repo clean",
    "test": "backstage-cli repo test",
    "test:all": "backstage-cli repo test --coverage",
    "lint": "backstage-cli repo lint --since origin/main",
    "lint:all": "backstage-cli repo lint",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check .",
    "new": "backstage-cli new --scope internal"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*",
      "plugins/*"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@backstage/cli": "^0.22.13",
    "@spotify/prettier-config": "^12.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17"
  },
  "prettier": "@spotify/prettier-config",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,mjs,cjs}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
     ],
    "*.{json,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@backstage/errors": "^1.2.2",
    "@manypkg/get-packages": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-promise-router": "^4.1.1",
    "node-gyp": "^9.4.0",
    "p5": "^1.7.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3"
  }
}
```

And my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "extends": "@backstage/cli/config/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "packages/*/src",
    "plugins/*/src",
    "plugins/*/dev",
    "plugins/*/migrations"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "dist-types",
    "rootDir": "."
  }
}
```

ls output of the /app directory:

`app-config.production.yaml  app-config.yaml  node_modules  package.json  packages  plugins  yarn.lock`

Here, app-config.production.yaml does not have overriding effect on app-config.yaml, as a note.
Thank you.

Comment: Did research here on SO give relevant answers or solutions to [`ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ENOENT%3A+no+such+file+or+directory%2C+scandir) ? If the answers did not help you, can you please link them and explain why they did not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: It seems that my minikube was using its own Docker runtime, not the local Docker runtime that I was using. So I changed the runtime environment to local Docker, problem solved.

If anyone has the same case, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I spent half a year integrating Backstage at my company and have created several plugins.

Make sure that the plugin has all of its dependencies and that you have also chown'd the owner to node:node.

Comment: Can you explain your comment a little further? While image gets created, yarn install has no errors and also plugins work fine locally so I think plugins have their dependency.  Additionally I’m chown’ing the tar files. What else should I chown?

Comment: Did you chown the folder when you did 'COPY plugins/inventory-backend/migrations /app/plugins/inventory-backend/migrations'?

Comment: Just added "--chown=node:node" to the line where I copy migrations but ended up with the same error, unfortunately. You have any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste your root package.json and tsconfig.json files in your original question, as well as the output of an ls of the /app directory in docker?

Comment: Added the info.

Comment: So I see nothing wrong there, check your plugin package.json and if you don't have this, add it, then run the build again:

"files":["dist","migrations/**/*.{js,d.ts}"]


https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/18065#issue-1736240469

Comment: Hi, that line was indeed missing. Added it and now migrations file is in my image, but still it does not get included on my pod and I'm getting the same error. I looked inside the container before it crashes, and the migrations file is really not in the pod. Also checked the "node" user's authorizations inside the image. The node user has its every privilege on the file. I don't see why the file is being excluded at the pod.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "migrations"
  ]
```

to your package.json to make the migrations be part of your built app